# How to trigger javascript after php submit?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Ok this is hard to explain.

```
 function m(val){
  var element=document.getElementById('othermethod');
  if(val=='others')
    element.style.display='block';
  else  
    element.style.display='none';
 }
```

---

```
<label>Payment Method</label><label id="star">*</label><br>
    <select id="input" name="pmethod" onchange='m(this.value);' required>

      <option> - Select a Method - </option>

      <option value="Cheque" <?php if(isset($_POST['pmethod']) && $_POST['pmethod'] =='Cheque' ){echo "selected";}?>>Cheque</option>

      <option value="Cash" <?php if(isset($_POST['pmethod']) && $_POST['pmethod'] =='Cash' ){echo "selected";}?>>Cash</option>

      <option value="Customer Bank In" <?php if(isset($_POST['pmethod']) && $_POST['pmethod'] =='Customer Bank In' ){echo "selected";}?>>Customer Bank In</option>

      <option value="mPos" <?php if(isset($_POST['pmethod']) && $_POST['pmethod'] =='mPos' ){echo "selected";}?>>mPos</option>

      <option value="iPay88" <?php if(isset($_POST['pmethod']) && $_POST['pmethod'] =='iPay88' ){echo "selected";}?>>iPay88</option>

  <option value="others" <?php if(isset($_POST['pmethod']) && $_POST['pmethod'] =='others' ){echo ' value="others" selected';}?>>Others</option><br>   
    </select>
<input type="text" name="othermethod" id="othermethod" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['othermethod'])) echo $_POST['othermethod'];?>" style='display:none;'/><br>
```

**My aim**: If user choose "others", then a input type text will display and let user to key in their input.

Now what i am doing is after this form is submitted, those input will remain so that user dont need to fill in again.

But the question is, everything works, only the "others" is not working. It did not trigger the javascript code after user submitted form.(which should display an input type text when user select "others").

Comment: So where do you call `Pack`?

Comment: The ID if the input is `othermethod`, not `otherpack`. With your function as it is right now you should get the error `Cannot read property 'style' of null`

Comment: @CBroe Sorry i copy the wrong function, i corrected it ady. It works at the 1st submit(which the text will display if user choose "others"), but after submit, the text did not display out.

Comment: @Seblor Sorry i copy the wrong function, i corrected it ady. It works at the 1st submit(which the text will display if user choose "others"), but after submit, the text did not display out.

Comment: So the only place where you are calling this, is the change event handler. Loading the page with given options selected is _not_ a “change”, so of course this will not fire. You have to call the function explicitly on page load. Or, you just output the `display:none` dynamically via PHP, so that JS doesn’t have to handle this case only after the page is loaded.

Comment: @CBroe so how should i do it? Finally somebody understand my problem T.T

Comment: You should execute the javascript from the document onload event handler or send the css from php directly..

Answer (score 0):

you have not given the id attribute in "others" so just add the id attribute and set it to "otherpack".

Comment: Sorry i copy the wrong function, i corrected it ady. It works at the 1st submit(which the text will display if user choose "others"), but after submit, the text did not display out.

Answer (score -1):

You have not used your function names and element names properly . Any way , not needed to call so many functions throughout one page , check the following codes which is derived from your code and it will solve your purpose .

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#input").on('change', function(){
        var val = document.getElementById('input').value ;
        if (val == 'others'){
            document.getElementById('othermethod').style.display='block';
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('othermethod').style.display='none';
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:-

```
<label>Payment Method</label><label id="star">*</label><br>
<select id="input" name="pmethod" required>

  <option> - Select a Method - </option>

  <option value="Cheque" <?php if(isset($_POST['pmethod']) && $_POST['pmethod'] =='Cheque' ){echo "selected";}?>>Cheque</option>

  <option value="Cash" <?php if(isset($_POST['pmethod']) && $_POST['pmethod'] =='Cash' ){echo "selected";}?>>Cash</option>

  <option value="Customer Bank In" <?php if(isset($_POST['pmethod']) && $_POST['pmethod'] =='Customer Bank In' ){echo "selected";}?>>Customer Bank In</option>

  <option value="mPos" <?php if(isset($_POST['pmethod']) && $_POST['pmethod'] =='mPos' ){echo "selected";}?>>mPos</option>

  <option value="iPay88" <?php if(isset($_POST['pmethod']) && $_POST['pmethod'] =='iPay88' ){echo "selected";}?>>iPay88</option>

  <option value="others" <?php if(isset($_POST['pmethod']) && $_POST['pmethod'] =='others' ){echo ' value="others" selected';}?>>Others</option><br>   
  </select>

<input type="text" name="othermethod" id="othermethod" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['othermethod'])) echo $_POST['othermethod'];?>" style='display:none;'/><br>
```

Comment: Sorry i copy the wrong function, i corrected it ady. It works at the 1st submit(which the text will display if user choose "others"), but after submit, the text did not display out.

Comment: Doesn't look like the OP is using jQuery. Neither did it solve his problem. Your code is doing the same thing in jQuery.